# Upgrade PHP on CentOs5

Tags: php, centos, centos5

This morning I used yum upgrade to upgrade from php 5.1.6 to 5.3+ I then went to one of my sites and found that it had crashed, error establishing database connection.

I found through this question [install php on linux from 1and1 VPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/304193/install-php-on-linux-from-1and1-vps) that this is because centos5 is outdated, and I was offered the alternative of doing it using individual packages by MadHatter.

I have just tried that solution and then checked my php version, and it hadn't upgraded. I have just learned that this is because my server software is Virtuozzo/Plesk and that these have a version of php of their own, seperate to that of the live sites, it turns out that I was working on the server's version of php with Yum.

Is there any way I can change yum to work on my version of php, or any other suggestions. My phpinfo() is at http://www.spotblue.co.uk/phpinfo.php

I am tearing out my hair, so any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is using PECL module (you need to upgrade other PHP modules as well), Try to upgrade/check version for php-mysql and php-mysqli , or any other module that you use on the web site.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are still running php 5.1.6:) Plesk will use system php installation and hence the system php upgrade via yum is sufficient. I seriously doubt that your system contains both php installed and this is causing you the trouble. confirm this by

```
php -qa |grep php-
```

In either case, I would suggest to remove the current php installation completely (after noting down the modules) and install php5.3 then from the default centOS repo.

```
php -qa | php- >> /root/myphp516.txt
rpm -e --nodeps `php -qa | php-`
yum install php53
```

This will install php 5. 3 only, for additional modules include them as well in the yum install with php53 prefix (refer /root/myphp516.txt for your old php modules list).